# How to increment counter and decrement it with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jtogglebutton

Hi guys I need assistance with incrementing a variable with just one value for a user and when the user clicks the same button the value decreases by one and this cycles continues. There is a situation similar in the below code:

```js
$(function() {
  var indicator = 0;
  $('#btn1').on('click', function() {
    $('#toggleIndicator').show();
    indicator++;
    alert('ON value : ' + indicator);
  })

  $('#btn2').on('click', function() {
    $('#toggleIndicator').hide();
    indicator--;
    alert('OFF value : ' + indicator);
  })
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.a {
  background-color: orange;
}
.b {
  background-color: gold;
}
.c {
  background-color: maroon;
}
.d {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a" id="toggleIndicator">
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn1" value="ON" />
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="OFF" />
```

but in my case I want the actions to be on one button just like on or off. Any way to do this please?

Comment: Did you try to write something yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function) {
   var state = true;
   var indicator = 0;

   $("#btn").click(function() {
     if(state) {
     indicator++;
     alert(indicator);
     state = false;
   } else {
     indicator--;
     alert(indicator);
     state = true;
   }
 });
});
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qjm9dz2g/2/